# How can i wrap this as one function instead of repeating it nine times?

Tags: javascript

Now Working (more) Prooertly

I got this simplified 'rubik's cube' effect on images here-

```
<a href="http://codepen.io/Nirsgv/pen/JYmrMK">codepen here</a>
```

Had to repeat this function nine times and thinking about how to wrap the functionality of the program effectively.
Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: PLEASE post the JS you've tried...

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does is it have to be in pure JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace your JavaScript with the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("mainImage" + i).onclick = changeImage;
}

function changeImage()
{
    this.setAttribute("class", "back" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1));
}
```

or with almost one-liner in jQuery:

```
$(".cont image").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("class", "back" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1));
});
```

My solution is not that universal - for example, you will need to change this code if you want to have 16 cells instead of 9 or if you rename your IDs \ classes. However, it is the shortest one :)

Actually, you don't need to know `id` of current cell to change the image.
If you want to get `id` within `changeImage` for some reason, you can extract it from element ID using `substr`:

```
function changeImage()
{
    var id = this.id.substr(9);
    console.log(id + " is clicked.");

    this.setAttribute("class", "back" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1));
}
```

Since our IDs look like `mainImage1`, `mainImage2` ... `mainImage9`, you can simply extract your `id` by using `this.id.substr(9)`. **[`substr(index)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)** method simply takes the substring of a string starting from a `index` position.

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/egnmweLy/1/)

Comment: Can you explain the use of the substr method in this function?

Comment: @user38455 It simply takes the 9-th+ symbol. It works because our id looks like "mainImage3" - remove first 9 characters and it becomes "3". For example, if you rename your ids to `image1`, `image2` etc., then you will need to use `this.id.substr(5)`. Check the update, please :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you can simply do:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".cont img");
for(var i in images){

    images[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        console.log(i, classArray[i]);
        e.target.setAttribute("class", classArray[i]);
        i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));
        console.log(classArray[i])
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question "how to wrap the functionality of the program effectively" to mean, how should you encapsulate your data and behaviour?

Looking at the code you have provided, I'd structure something like the below...

```
var MyApp = (function(){

    var _classArray = ["back1", "back2", "back3", "back4", "back5", "back6", "back7", "back8", "back9"];
    var _images = [

        document.getElementById("mainImage1"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage2"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage3"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage4"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage5"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage6"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage7"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage8"),
        document.getElementById("mainImage9")
    ];

    function _init()
    {

        _bindToUIEvents();
    }

    function _bindToUIEvents()
    {
        for(var i=0; i < _images.size; i++)
        {
            _images.onclick = function () 
            {
                console.log(i, _classArray[i]);
                _images[i].setAttribute("class", _classArray[i]);

                i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9));

                console.log(_classArray[i])
            };
        }
    }

    return {

        init: _init()

    };

})();

$(document).ready(function(){
   MyApp.init;
});
```